# Python newbie: old C++ code for interfacing with Python uses deprecated boost/python/numeric.hpp instead of NumPy. How to update?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, numpy, boost

I'm using Python 2.7.10 on a Mac (10.12.6).  Apologies in advance for any silly comments: I am a Python newbie and also am not that experienced with C++.

I need to compile an old C++-based code that interfaces with Python.  A couple of the .cpp files use the deprecated "boost/python/numeric.hpp" as an include and for making arrays:

```
#include <boost/python/numeric.hpp>
const py::numeric::array& X
```

I have spent a couple of days now on trying to figure out how to deal with this, but just can't turn up any documentation that makes sense as a newbie.  I would be very grateful if someone would please point me in the right direction.  One thing I did come across was this post:

> [how to return numpy.array from boost::python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701514/how-to-return-numpy-array-from-boostpython)

where one suggestion involves using

```
#include <numpy/ndarrayobject.h>
```

However, I just cannot figure out how to use it to translate my old code.

Thank you for any help.

---

Edit in response to sehe:
The code is too large to post in its entirety, but the errors all seem to be related to:

```
#include <boost/python/numeric.hpp>
```

I'm pretty sure I need to use:

```
#include <numpy/ndarrayobject.h>
```

However, I can't figure out how to change the code that refers to the arrays. 
 This seems like such a simple thing, but I haven't been able to find any documentation.  Below are specific examples of where the deprecated code is an issue (please let me know if I can make this more understandable)

In the main() file "PyMain.cpp":

```
// Include from Boost
#include <boost/python.hpp>
namespace py = boost::python;         

// Other includes for the code PyCalculator
# XXX...
# XXX...

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PyCalculator)
{
    // Set numpy as the numeric::array engine
    py::numeric::array::set_module_and_type("numpy", "ndarray");

XXX // (Other non-problematic code
}
```

Here's an example of another file, "Auxiliary .cpp"

The error shown in the terminal is:

```
PyAux.cpp: fatal error: 
          'boost/python/numeric.hpp' file not found


#include "PyAux.hpp"
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/ndarrayobject.h>

// Boost includes
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numeric.hpp>
#include <boost/python/slice.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
namespace py = boost::python;

// Other includes
#include <PyAux/Math/Other/Core>

namespace PyCalculator {
... XXX
// There are functions like:
    static auto initializeWithArray(const py::numeric::array& array) -> boost::shared_ptr<VectorType>
    { //...XXX 
        const py::numeric::array& X
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a small, self-contained example of a minimal C++ module and Python user-code, I (or someone else) could try my hand at it

Comment: Thank you, sehe.  I would really appreciate that.  I'll try to prepare one (it's a huge code).  I was hoping that it would be possible to simply use "#include <numpy/ndarrayobject.h>" instead of "#include <boost/python/numeric.hpp>" and then use some array container within ndarrayobject, but it looks like this won't be possible.

Comment: If "it's <strike>a</strike> huge code" then clearly it's beyond the scope of your question. Your question is specifically about the interface code, which should be doable <40 LoC

Comment: Yes, you're right, sehe. All the errors are specifically related to boost/python/numeric.hpp. My challenge is coming up with a representative example as a newbie. I'm working on it, but it might take me a little while!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to comment out:

```
//#include <boost/python/numeric.hp
```

and replace it with:

```
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
```